# Batch getting URLs in Chrome Inspect-Page-Sources

Tags: google-chrome, batch, internet, clipboard

Below is a screenshot of **chrome browser** in `flickr.com/explore`

Note that we are inspecting something.

Inspect - Sources - Page

**Q)** In this state, how can I get the all URLs below top/combo.staticflickr.com/zz **at once**?
For just a single item, I can right click it and select 'Copy link address` as shown in the screenshot. But I have no idea for batch case.

I can manipulate text contained in a clipboard, so I think I can achieve the final goal if it is just possible to get (export to clipboard) the whole structure of `Inspect - Sources - Page`.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to get the URLs from there?

Comment: If I can get URLs below top/combo.staticflickr.com/zz, any method is welcome. It is generally not possible to see what exist below top/combo.staticflickr.com/zz due to server security.. So for me, one possible method is to inspect with chrome browser.

Comment: And sometimes for example, for same image, its URL changes in realtime. In this case the surest way to access the image URL is using chrome's `Inspect` feature.

Comment: https://www.mattjennings.net/extracting-urls-web-page-chrome-developer-tools Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you, but It is far from the goal. Executing the javascript code only shows just a part of URLs  available on inspect - sources - page.

Comment: To be more prercise, there are many URLs which can be `exclusively` obtained by the code con mattjennings.net/..,  and also there are many other URLs which can be `exclusively` obtained by inspect - sources - page.